# How do I 'AND' a 'media' and a 'support' query?

Tags: css

Hi I have these two CSS clauses, and I would like to 'AND' them together:

`@supports not (-ms-ime-align:auto)`

`@media only screen and (min-width: 981px)`

embedding the two together works, but it breaks my theme (already raised a support ticket with them): ie. `@support {@media{}}`

also tried '&&', 'and' and ','

eg.
`@supports not (-ms-ime-align:auto) and @media only screen and (min-width: 981px)`

they didn't work.

Comment: Like I explained, embedding/nesting the two together works, but it breaks my theme

Comment: Can you post the full CSS of the nested solution you tried? The answer to the question is "it's not possible!" As far as I can see.

Comment: How does it break your theme?

Comment: The theme's CSS editor does not support nesting yet, it throws an exception.